# Perl: Why do I get error "The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file

I am trying to run the below perl code from Windows batch file but getting error `The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`
The script ran fine in eclipse.My ultimate goal is to run this perl script periodically using windows task scheduler, hence running it from a batch file. 
Is there any other ways with which we can achieve my goal of running perl script on windows periodically?
I want my script to be functional across platforms, coz I have plans to run it from a mac as well.

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Data::Dumper;
  use File::Find::Rule;

 my $basedir="G:\/My_Workspaces";
 my @exclude_dirs= qw(.foo);

#Fetching all the workspaces under base dir excluding the ones in @exclude_dirs
my @subdirs =
              File::Find::Rule
              ->mindepth(1)
              ->maxdepth(1)
              ->not_name(@exclude_dirs)
              ->directory
              ->in($basedir);

#Formating list of workspaces by removing the full path
s{^\Q$basedir\E/}{} for @subdirs;
```

Comment: Unless there's more in this file than you've shown, it's a Perl source file, not a Windows batch file. Is this exactly what you have? Also, note that only Windows support volume letters like `G:\My_Workspaces`

Comment: @Borodin : The value of variable `$basedir` will change for mac. This is the only part of my perl code which uses directory names. Any idea why am I getting the error? Thanks !

Comment: Don't escape `/`, it's a normal character. `X:/foo/bar` should work on Windows.

Comment: Is that error message coming from Perl, or from Windows? Also, you don't need to invoke your script from a batch file in order to call it via a Windows scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is exactly the contents of your file, then you're asking Windows' command interpreter to process Perl source code, which it can't do

If you really need to create a batch file that has your Perl code embedded in it, then take a look at the [`pl2bat`](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.1/win32/bin/pl2bat.pl) utility, which will do exactly that

A command like

```
pl2bat myperl.pl
```

will create a file `myperl.bat` that will run on the Windows command line and has your Perl source code embedded inside it. But that file is non-portable because it uses Windows commands that aren't recognised on a Mac or Linux platform

Comment: It worked like charm. Thanks for letting me know this new thing `pl2bat` today.

Answer (score 1):

Either something doesn't know how to execute your Perl script, or your Perl script is being interpreted by something other than `perl`.

This could due to a problem with your file associations (or a lack thereof). Determining the exact cause would require more information.

In any case, executing `perl` with your script as a parameter rather than executing the script directly should solve the problem.

In other words, execute

```
perl script.pl
```

instead of

```
script.pl
```